# can't find name Amcharts in angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, amcharts

I am trying to use `amcharts` in a native way without any service of angular2.

I have doing the following steps:

1. I have installed `amcharts` package via `npm`.

2.I have installed  `amcharts-typings` via `npm`.

3.I have add the `amChart` scripts to `angular-cli.json`.

4. I have googled this issue and found out all solutions don't work for me.

Does anybody knows how can we use `amcharts` in native way in `TypeScript` and particularly in `angular-cli` without using any directives or services.

**I got an error from webpack: cannot find name 'Amcharts'.**

This is my code:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';

  ngOnInit(){
    this.makeChart();
  }

  makeChart(){
    let options = {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  } ],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

}
    AmCharts.ready(function(){
        AmCharts.makeChart('amcharts',options,0);
    })

  }

}
```

`

my angular-cli json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "amcharts-ng"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: May be you should try to use this (https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2) lib?

Comment: Yea I know this library, but in this way, I am not using amcharts typings and can't create classes which amcharts typings gives me.

Comment: can you post your angular-cli.json ? do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: as far as i know  //<reference if deprecated... like "@types/nprogress": "0.0.29",

Comment: posted, I got the following error from webpack:
'can't find name amcharts'

Comment: @happyZZR1400 you are right, I can use types without the refrence, my bad mistake.
Still I can't know why webpack doesn't recongine amcharts name

Comment: any help will be welcome,so far not answer has come up with a real solution for my problem: which is using amcharts with typings in angular-cli. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `window.AmCharts` instead of just `AmCharts`. Otherwise you may need to import from `"'@amcharts/amcharts3-angular'"`.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/issues/20